# Query to Return Top Items for Each Distinct Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, greatest-n-per-group

If I have a table with the following fields

```
ID, SomeFK, SomeTime
```

How would I write a query return the latest/top 3 items (based on `SomeTime`) for each `SomeFK`.

So, the result might look like

```
SomeFK    Sometime
0         2012-07-05 
0         2012-07-04 
0         2012-07-03 
1         2012-07-03 
1         2012-07-02 
1         2012-07-01 
2         2012-07-03 
2         2012-07-02 
2         2012-07-01 
....etc....
```

Returning the latest items for a particular `SomeFK` is easy, but i just can't think how to do it for the above. I also feel it should be dead simple!

**EDIT:**

Apologies, I missed a key bit of information. this is for SQL2000, so `ROW_NUMBER()` can't be used!

Comment: See the ["solution based on concatenation"](http://www.sqlmag.com/content1/topic/optimizing-top-n-per-group-queries/catpath/departments/page/3) section here for one method that works in 2000.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you use CTE in 2000?

Comment: @podiluska - No they are 2005+ only. You can use derived tables though. Actually just realised the earlier link isn't suitable as only works for N=1. [Another 2000 method is here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SelectTopNByGroup#SQL2000)

Comment: That last linked worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT SomeFk, SomeTime 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeFK ORDER BY sometime desc) rn
    FROM yourtable
    ) v
WHERE rn<=3
ORDER BY somefk, rn
```

For SQL 2000, I recommend upgrading to a supported platform.

But if you insist.

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where
    (select COUNT(*)
     from yourtable
     where somefk = t1.somefk
     and sometime>=t1.sometime
    ) <=3
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed a key bit of information. this is for SQL2000, so ROW_NUMBER() can't be used!

Comment: I've accepted this as the best solution. I would add the following caveat to the end: `and sometime is not null
order by somefk, sometime desc`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you correctly, can you not select the `max` SomeTime and then group, like this:

```
select SomeFK, max(SomeTime) 
from Table
group by SomeFK
```

I could be off the mark here, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean by latest.

Comment: By latest, I meant 'top by time'. the example should clarify

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [this link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SelectTopNByGroup#SQL2000)  (supplied as a comment to the original question). One soltion is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, SomeFK, SomeTime
FROM SomeTable t1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 3 ID
               FROM SomeTable t2
              WHERE t2.SomeFK= t1.SomeFK
              ORDER BY SomeTime DESC)
ORDER BY SomeFK, SomeTime DESC
```

Although I've prefer the accepted solution now.

Comment: The potential disadvantage is that you can't parameterise a top command - ie if you had a procedure that wanted to return the top N by group... But that probably doesn't apply in this situation

Comment: Actually that query runs like a dog as well. I'm going to bin it abd go with yours

Comment: Its not. Completed in 182 seconds. I stopped the other after 900 :-)