# Select 50 percent rows of each unique user

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is what my table looks like

```
Id | User | TestedGame | GameBuildID | TestType |TDate

1| Chan | Game One | GBI010115 | Maps | 01-02-2015

2| TedD | Game two | GBI010615 | Maps | 01-22-2015

3| Chan | Game One | GBI010315 | Maps | 01-12-2015

4| John | Game thr | GBI010715 | Grap | 01-02-2015

5| Chan | Game two | GBI010415 | Maps | 01-07-2015

6| Samy | Game thr | GBI010115 | Grap | 01-02-2015
```

Table runs into 1000s of rows. I hope the field names are self explanatory. This is a table to keep track of games tested. The build id, part of the game tested, name of the game, test type and test date are saved. ID is unique and is the primary key.

The table is saved in a accdb file.

Question:

How do I select 50% of every user's tests?

SQL

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT User, Id, TestedGame, testtype, GameBuildID, Tdate FROM Table Where Tdate >#01-01-2015# and Tdate < #31-01-2015# ORDER BY rnd(Id)
```

This however does not give equal distribution to different users.

Current output:

I get 50% of all tests done in a month. User distribution is not uniform. For eg. If Chan tested 100 game builds per month, I don't get 50 of Chan's game builds. And if some new tester only tested 2 game builds, I end up getting no results from that tester.

Expected output

```
50% of Userone's rows

50% of User two's rows

.

.

.

50% of nth user's rows
```

I am running the sql as an access query.

Edit:

Related question:

[Query to Return Top Items for Each Distinct Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966774/query-to-return-top-items-for-each-distinct-column-value)

Comment: Post your expected output.

Comment: @selvats edited body

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery like this (air code):
`SELECT User, Id, TestedGame, testtype, GameBuildID, Tdate FROM Table Where ID IN(
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT P.Id FROM Table AS P Where P.User=Table.User AND Tdate >#01-01-2015# and Tdate < #31-01-2015# ORDER BY rnd(Id)
)`