# How to Join only first row, disregard further matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

```
Table Users: 
UserID  |  Name

Table Cars: 
CarID | Car Name | FK_UserID
```

A user can have more than 1 car.

I want to join each user with 1 car only, not more.

Having looked at other threads here,
I've tried the following:

```
Select users.UserID, users.name, carid
from Users
join cars
on users.UserID = 
    (
    select top 1 UserID
    from users
    where UserID = CarID
    )
```

But it still returns more than 1 match for each user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query to Return Top Items for Each Distinct Column Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966774/query-to-return-top-items-for-each-distinct-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below using `ROW_NUMBER()` function

```
select userid, username, carname
from
(
Select users.UserID as userid, 
users.name as username, 
cars.carname as carname,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY users.UserID ORDER BY users.UserID) AS r
from Users
join cars
on users.UserID = cars.FK_UserID
) XXX
where r = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as
(select row_number() over(partition by userid order by carid) as rn,
 * from cars)
select u.userid, x.carid,  x.carname 
from users u join x on x.userid = u.userid
where x.rn = 1;
```

This is one way to do it using `row_number` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
select u.UserID, 
    u.name, 
    (select TOP 1 carid 
     from cars c 
     where u.UserID = c.FK_UserID 
     order by carid) carid -- Could be ordered by anything
from Users u
 -- where only required if you only want users with cars
where exists (select * from car c where u.UserID = c.FK_UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to do a subquery and use a `group-by` in it to return only 1 user and a car for each user. Then join that to the outer user table.

Here is an example:

```
select *
from user_table u
    join   (
           select userid
                , max(carname)
           from cars
           group by userid

           ) x on x.userId = u.userId
```

or you could use the `row_number()` examples above if you want a specific order (either this example or theirs will do the trick)